# Idiomatic way to count org-mode subtrees?

Tags: org-mode

Is there an idiomatic way to count org-mode subtrees?

I searched here on emacs.sx and other search engines, but I could not find an answer.

I know one could easily count subtrees with a regex, but I was wondering if the org API has means to fulfill more sophisticated counting needs, like,

- How many second-level headlines under current tree?
- How many third-level headlines in total in the current buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`org-map-entries` is a typical way to do this:

> (org-map-entries FUNC &optional MATCH SCOPE &rest SKIP)
>
> Call FUNC at each headline selected by MATCH in SCOPE.

It returns the results of `FUNC`, so you can count them to get the number of headlines that matched `MATCH` (which is a `org-agenda` style search string).  `SCOPE` can be set to `tree` to check only the tree point is on, `nil` to search the entire buffer, `region` to search the current region and a few other more specialized ones.

If you only care about the number of results, the function doesn't have to do anything.  Your examples turn into:

- `(length (org-map-entries t "LEVEL=2" 'tree))`
- `(length (org-map-entries t "LEVEL=3" nil))`

The `MATCH` string can search for tags, properties or anything else you can do an agenda search for.

Comment: Jinx! Great minds always meet :-)

Answer (score 5):

These are untested but they should be close:

```
(length (org-map-entries t "LEVEL=2" 'tree))

(length (org-map-entries t "LEVEL=3" 'file))
```

`org-map-entries` is very powerful and can do a lot more than counting things: see the [doc](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Using-the-Mapping-API) for details (which includes an example that's very close to this).

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, yours is as good as erikstokes'. Since it cannot be done, I had to give precedence to timing. Thank you so much for the link.

Comment: That is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

And here's the non/less-idiomatic way:

```
(defun count-subtrees ()
  (interactive)
  (let (lvs)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (while (outline-previous-heading)
        (let* ((hl (org-element-at-point))
               (lv (org-element-property :level hl)))
          (push lv lvs))))
    (let* ((depth (cl-sort lvs #'<))
           (min-lv (car depth))
           (max-lv (car (last depth))))
      (cl-loop for lv from min-lv to max-lv
               for count = (cl-count-if (lambda (elt)
                                          (= elt lv))
                                        lvs)
               collect (print (cons lv count))))))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested the code a few hours back and it was not working, but now it works perfectly. I cannot accept it as answer for the "idiomatic way", but still I appreciate the code and upvoted. Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: Phew. I was that close from a downvote. Anyhow, thanks for the kind words.